UnitTest on init block in ViewModel don't stop in suspend function
I have this ViewModel with a standar init{} block that call a fetch Data function.
class HomeViewModel(
   private val repository: CitiesRepository,
   private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
): ViewModel() {
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(HomeState())
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()

init {
    println("in init block") // Log
    fetchData()
}

private fun fetchData() {
    viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
        println("Corrutina iniciada") // Log
        _uiState.update { _uiState.value.copy(isLoading = true) }
        val data = repository.fetchDummyData()
        _uiState.update { _uiState.value.copy(data = data, isLoading = false) }
        println("Corrutina finalizada") // Log
    }
}

and then I want to test it.
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class HomeViewModelTest {

  private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel
  private val repository: CitiesRepository = mockk()
  private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()
  private val scope = TestScope(testDispatcher)

@Before
fun setUp() {
    coEvery { repository.fetchDummyData() } returns listOf(
        "New York",
        "Los Angeles",
        "San Francisco"
    )
    Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    viewModel = HomeViewModel(repository, dispatcher = testDispatcher)
}

What happens is that the viewModel is initialized and the init block is run. And I cant' test the initial state on viewModel.uiState values
this is my println result
> in init block 
> Corrutina iniciada 
> Corrutina finalizada
> HomeViewModelTest -> initial state is loading

So, the coroutine is started and ended before enteris the test function
this fails on the first assert
@Test
fun `ViewModel initial state is loading`() = scope.runTest {
    println("HomeViewModelTest -> initial state is loading")
    assert(HomeState() == viewModel.uiState.value)
    assertTrue(viewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)

    // Esperar a que fetchCities se complete
    println("HomeViewModelTest -> avanzar en corutina")
    testDispatcher.scheduler.advanceUntilIdle()

what could be the reason
I know thta there is turbine for similar test, but I want to know what is wrong in my test.

By creating a HomeViewModel you queue up fetchData's coroutine into testDispatcher. When runTest is called it queues up the test as a new coroutine to the same single thread dispatcher, so it is executed after fetchData.
From runTest documentation:

Executes testBody as a test in a new coroutine, returning TestResult.

Documentation on StandardTestDispatcher:

When you start new coroutines on a StandardTestDispatcher, they are queued up on the underlying scheduler, to be run whenever the test thread is free to use.

A couple of side notes:
There is no need for TestScope for this particular test, runTest will use the Main dispatcher if it is set.

If the Main dispatcher has been replaced with a TestDispatcher, any newly-created TestDispatchers will automatically use the scheduler from the Main dispatcher, including the StandardTestDispatcher created by runTest if no other dispatcher is passed to it.

Also, ViewModel shouldn't care about dispatchers. Instead, each suspend function should decide on its own which dispatcher to use to be main-safe.
Taking all this into account, your code might look like this:
HomeViewModel:
private fun fetchData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {    // dispatcher removed!
        println("Corrutina iniciada")
        _uiState.update { _uiState.value.copy(isLoading = true) }
        val data = repository.fetchDummyData()
        _uiState.update { _uiState.value.copy(data = data, isLoading = false) }
        println("Corrutina finalizada")
    }
}

Test:
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class HomeViewModelTest {

    private val testDispatcher = StandardTestDispatcher()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    @Test
    fun `ViewModel initial state is loading`() = runTest {
        val viewModel = HomeViewModel()
        println("HomeViewModelTest -> state before coroutine launch")
        assert(HomeState() == viewModel.uiState.value)
        assertTrue(viewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)

        println("HomeViewModelTest -> resuming coroutine")
        advanceUntilIdle()
        assertFalse(viewModel.uiState.value.isLoading)
    }
}

